Is it permissible to do sparring training with a girl?
I recently started boxing classes and would like to know if it permissible for me to do sparring practice with a girl around my age if the coach tells us to do so.
The thick boxing gloves are worn, i wear pants below the knees and we  avoid punching the face. Since touching a women is haram, I would like to know if light punches in the form of training set by a coach is also haram.
I don't choose to train with a girl but the coach sometimes pairs us up for sparring practice.
